# Pass a generated data frame from one function to another

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I am working on a application that takes multiple excel files from the user, does some stuff to them and returns a new excel file. The problem I am encountering is that I do not know how to input the paths the user gives into my compile function.

This is the function that asks the user for their input upon a button press.

```
def getFile1():
    dat1 = filedialog.askopenfilename(
        initialdir = "/", title = "File Selection",
        filetypes = (("Excel Files", "*.xlsx"), ("All Files", "*.*")))
    lbl1.config(text=dat1)
    df1 = pd.read_excel(r'' + str(dat1), skiprows = 1)
    return df1
```

For test purposes, lets say I want to print the `.head()` of the data frame using the compile function.

```
def compile():
    print(df1.head())
```

How do I do this? Simply passing df1 like `def compile(df1):` tells me that it's missing the required positional argument. I tried a few other things but all to no avail.

Edit: I tried to avoid writing the full code in order to keep the post short and concise but for added clarity, here it is with all the fluff taken out.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import os.path
from tkinter import ttk
from pandas import *
import pandas as pd

def getFile1():
    dat1 = filedialog.askopenfilename(
        initialdir = "/", title = "Select File",
        filetypes = (("Excel Files", "*.xlsx"), ("All Files", "*.*")))
    lbl1.config(text=dat1)
    df1 = pd.read_excel(r'' + str(dat1), skiprows = 1)
    print(df1.head())
    return df1

def compile(df1):
    print(df1.head())


master = Tk()

lbl1 = Label(width = 70)
lbl1.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

Button(text="Excel File", command=getFile1, width = 30, height = 2).grid(row=1, column=0)
Button(text="Execute Programm", command=compile, width = 30, height = 2).grid(row = 2, column = 0)

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Seems that you are missing to specify the required argument of the `compile` function: `def compile(df1): ...`

Answer (score 0):

if you are using class it should be:

```py
class MyCuteClass():

 def compile (self, df1):
  ...

 def callCompile(self):
  ...
  self.compile(sendingDf1)
```

Usage

```py
myclass = new MyCuteClass()
myclass.compile(yourDf1)
```

Comment: I don't understand this answer. I don't use a class. Do I need to use one if I intend to make this work?

Comment: Nope, your code is fine, I was expecting you are using class, but I guess the error is caused by not adding argument on your compile function which is should be `def compile(df1): `

Comment: I did add df1 to compile. I mentioned so in the post as well. It just tells me that it misses a required positional argument.

Comment: Im not quite sure on the error message feels like it missing something, can you share fully the error message? mostly likely the error is cause when using class base method

Comment: I added the reproducable code as a edit. I reckon it's something obvious that I just don't see as a beginner in python.

Comment: Im not seeing anything that causes error, the code was fine, but Im not seeing the code stating how the `compile` function was use

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244252/discussion-between-squary94-and-forbidden).